# Php syntax issues

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php... This is wordpress. What is the issue here? It's a simple for each loop...

```
<?php
    foreach( $how_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
    echo '<li><a href="#section_' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sub_nav_name', true); . '">' . the_title(); . '</a></li>';
    $nav_items[] = html_entity_decode(get_the_title(), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: I don't know... what IS the issue? It might help if you told us what error you are getting.

Comment: what is `foreach( ... ) :` ?

Comment: @sircapsalot shorthand syntax

Comment: Remove `endforeach` and the colon after `foreach (...)` and you should be fine. Note that whilst PHP and Python have the same first letter, they are not the same.

Comment: @AlienWebguy learn something every day!

Comment: @MikeBrant The issue is that nothing is displaying on the page. There are no errors displaying. I am new to this. Perhaps instead of sarcasm, you would point me in the direction of learning how to display errors.

Comment: Oh, I forget to say 'and use curly braces instead' at the end of my comment.

Comment: @iggy2012 Google, Stackoverflow, and php.net itself have plenty of information on how to turn on error display/logging in PHP.  It should be one of the very first fundamental things you understand when starting with any new language. Had you turned on error display/logging you could have saved yourself the trouble of even having to ask this question as it would have told you exactly where you have a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `;` at the end of the functions

```
echo '<li><a href="#section_' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sub_nav_name', true) . '">' . the_title() . '</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple things here you should take note of.

**1) You have semicolons in the middle of your code:**

```
echo '<li><a href="#section_' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sub_nav_name', true); . '">' . the_title(); . '</a></li>';
// Should be:
echo '<li><a href="#section_' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sub_nav_name', true) . '">' . the_title() . '</a></li>';
```

**2) `endforeach` is using "alternate" syntax:**

Alternate PHP syntax should be avoided whenever possible, for the sake of standards, readability and to prevent the next guy who has to read your code from hunting you down and stabbing you with a rusty knife.

Because these syntaxes are "alternate", it can safely be assumed that these are not the recommended method of performing operations. While they do work and there is not currently any plan to deprecate this functionality, I would not count on them for the long-term as PHP begins to reel in it's out of control methodologies.

```
foreach( $how_posts as $post ) :
// Should be:
foreach( $how_posts as $post ) {

and

endforeach;
// Should be:
}
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
foreach($how_posts as $post) {
  setup_postdata($post);
  echo '<li><a href="#section_' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sub_nav_name', true) . '">' . the_title() . '</a></li>';
  $nav_items[] = html_entity_decode(get_the_title(), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: Not that I use it, but why is the alternate syntax to be avoided?

Comment: I'd like to know too. And could you please provide a link to the docs about the alternate syntax?

Comment: Because the next person who needs to maintain your code won't hate you. Also note that next person may just be the future you.

Comment: using alternative syntax for control structures is valid according to the php docs [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: It is valid syntax. So is `eval($_REQUEST['some_var'])`. Can and should are not the same thing.

Comment: However @joshua. Trust me the alternative syntax isn't going anywhere.

Comment: I'm with @PeeHaa, it's absurd to think this is an okay way of programming in PHP. Go learn VisualBasic if you're all for overly verbose expressions.

Comment: @JoshuaBurns I agree it is not a good method of programming PHP. However, it is not wrong or incorrect syntax either. It is perfectly acceptable and legal PHP syntax. The OP can write his/her code as they please. This is merely a personal choice and a good suggestion but not a requirement.

Comment: @PeeHaa are you saying the using alternate syntax is as dangerous as using `eval()`? @JoshuaBurns isn't the ternary operator `$a = (1 == $b) ? 'Yes' : 'No';` an alternate syntax? Should I not be using those either?

Comment: @Sean No it was just my way of telling you that because you can do something doesn't mean you should do something. My beef with the alternative syntax is that when I'm scanning code I don't want to think about what I am seeing. using alternative syntax makes it a bit harder to see exactly what is going on. Using the ternary operator is having the same issue.

Comment: @PeeHaa makes sense, just wanted to make sure I was not missing anything.

Comment: @Sean, ternary operations are more difficult to read than if statements, and that's why it is suggested one does not nest ternaries. in some casese their use is justified, however due to their single-line readability. the point is php was designed to be a language similar in syntax to c. endfor, endif, etc. were added by some moron that wanted to make PHP appear more friendly to VB programmers and in doing so, has created the discussion we're not having. :)

Comment: @Sean Also note that my opinions may be a bit biased, because I had to work with a lot of code from others in my life and you won't believe the crap I've seen and had to debug. Using the alternative `foreach` is *often* used in templates, because some people think it is nicer in that case. But I have always preferred to limit the wtf/m (wtf's per minute) in code even if it is for something as simple as that.

Comment: Note that at least the Zend Framework coding style recommends to use this alternate syntax in the template files. This is because a closing curly brace inside a PHP tag after plenty of HTML code usually does not explain enough about which opened loop or if is supposed to be closed. The alternate syntax provides more clarity in this case.